# Good coding patterns in RShiny applications?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

What are some good resources/examples for good coding patterns to follow in RShiny applications?

I feel I am following two bad patterns in the shiny applications I am creating.

1. To make things react to user changes properly, I seem to end up wrapping most parts of `server.r` in `observe()`.
2. At the beginning of each `observe()`, I want the expression to rerun if any one of a whole bunch of inputs change.

   - Ideally, I would like to put `input[change_set]` where `change_set` is a character vector of input names, however this gives an error of `Error in [.reactivevalues: Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed.`

     - (or if I use `input[[change_set]]`: `Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues`)
   - What I end up doing to make things work is including multiple lines of `input$var1`, `input$var2`, ..., `input$var15`. This feels very wrong.

I am not making use of any functions like: `reactive()`, `reactiveValues()`, `isolate()`, `withReactiveDomain()`, `makeReactiveBinding()`, ... . I am guessing that I probably should be, but I don't know how to use them.

The solution to this problem is likely to be me rereading the small print in the documentation and reading code from example applications. Does anybody know any good quality resources for this?

Comment: I always sugest watching these videos https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/ . Keep in mind that Shiny has changed a lot since its first version. New functions have simplified a lot of things and some of the older functions are not as needed as they used to be (since `observeEvent`/`eventReactive` were created, I almost never use `isolate`).